# Using AJAX and jQuery to store data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am looking for a way to use AJAX and jQuery to store data from one form in another without losing the values.  I want to be able to keep this data away from the front end user and allow them to remove the information should they wish to.  I need to be able to get this information out when the user submits the data.  I would like to be able to store the values in an associative PHP array if possible, for example:

```
<?php
    $information = array(
        "first_information"=>array(
            "name"=>"Sam Swift",
            "age"=>21
        ),
        "second_information"=>array(
            "name"=>"Example Name",
            "age"=>31
        )
    );
?>
```

I would have used a database for this but because of volume this will not be possible. I want to keep the data away from the user so that they have no access to it at all, the data should be held where the user has no way to see it, access it or change it. This is due to the nature of the data and all of it should be as secure as possible.

Comment: Different forms as in different subsequently visited pages?

Comment: @Jean-Paul, it would only be one form that is visited, but I would like to store the values in another to keep the data "safe" and then on form submission, use a function in the second form to store the data. The second form would never be visited by the user or anyone for that matter, it is simply a "holding" page

Comment: you should use hidden fields or data atributes to hold information if this what you want to do.

Comment: @SamSwift What do you mean by *keeping the data safe*? Can't you just use `<input type="hidden" ..` in your first form? As in [**hidden fields**](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms07.htm)?

Comment: @Jean-Paul, this will still allow the data to be accessed by the user and intercept any post that would be made. This is something I want to avoid at all costs due to the nature of the data

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 Exactly my thought as well.

Comment: @SamSwift What do you mean by *allowing the user to access the data*? Both forms and hidden input fields are visible in the DOM. Ajax won't change that. So try to rephrase your question please.

Comment: @Jean-Paul, I will make an amendment to my question

Comment: you can send data to server with ajax if you insist on user not to see content or modify it

Comment: @ConvertToInt32, what would be the best way to do this? Do you know a link to a tutorial for this? (I am rather new to jQuery and AJAX)

Comment: @SamSwift you can benefit  from any documentation related ajax-jquery,i assuming that you have two form and when user fills the first you want to save it ?

Comment: You have to store the data somewhere. Either you post it to the server and store it in the database, togerther with a session variable to identify the user, or you could store it in a cookie on the client side, but there it is not safe from manipulation, or store it in a hidden field, which isn't safe either. You could use encryption and a checksum or hash to have a fairly robust way to ensure data integrity.

Comment: @Jean-Paul is correct. Its a security thing, You can still send bad data, If you have a `<select>` you can change the values of the `<option>` from the client machine using standard browser tools. Saving it to a local source only opens you up to data-injection.

Comment: @SamSwift did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Ivan, as yet, I have not unfortunately, I am working on something other than this for the time being and will be coming back to this at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any information that you store client-side is naturally going to be accessible and mutable by the client.  If this sensitive data is data that the user is entering, then you really shouldn't worry about them manipulating the data (because that is what they are supposed to be doing).  If however it is data that is being sent by the server - and never displayed or used in that form by the client - this is data that should never leave the server in the first place.

Ajax is not specifically a solution to this problem - whether you send the data asynchronously (i.e., piecemeal with Ajax) or as a full HTTP post is immaterial.  You need to store the sensitive data **on the server only** along with a session ID to associate it with the client session.

Without knowing exactly what data you are storing nor what you are doing with it, it is difficult to advise you how to proceed.  You should rethink how you are structuring your application if you are sending sensitive data for the client to work with.  The client should only ever see the **input** and the **results**.  The processing should be done on the server.

For example: perhaps your user is adding an amount to a bank balance.  The user enters the amount on the client. but you don't want the client to see or be able to modify the actual value.  You *could* send the balance to the client, perform the addition operation, then send the total back to the server.  Far better would be for the client to send the amount to add to the server, which would then add the value to the balance, and return a confirmation for the client to display.